# Formula for spliting and remove words in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I remove some words in excel sheet. For examle

I have a url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. I just need 'questions/ask'from that. Should cut 'https://stackoverflow.com/' which is common. Can anybody help me with a formula for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

general version:

```
=MID(A1,LEN("http://stackoverflow.com/")+1,LEN(A1)-LEN("http://stackoverflow.com/"))
```

or shorter:

```
=MID(A1,26,LEN(A1)-25)
```